# php mysql insert data with multiple rows in one page and one query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, css

This is MySql query:

```
if ($_POST["ok"] == "OK") {
  $updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE attend 
  SET 
  at_status=%s,
  at_remarks=%s WHERE at_tt_idx=%s",

                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['attend'], "text"),
                         GetSQLValueString($_POST['remarks'], "text"),
                         GetSQLValueString($_POST['tt_idx'], "int"));

  mysql_select_db($database_conn, $conn);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($updateSQL, $conn) or die(mysql_error());


if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form3") && $_POST["ok"] != "OK") {
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO attend (at_matrix_no, at_status, at_remarks, at_staff_idx, at_sb_name , at_class, at_sb_code, at_tt_idx) VALUES ( %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",

                      GetSQLValueString($_POST['st_matrix_no'], "text"),
                      GetSQLValueString($_POST['attend'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['remarks'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['tt_staff_idx'], "int"),
                         GetSQLValueString($_POST['sb_name'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['tt_class'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['sb_code'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_GET['tt_idx'], "int"));

  mysql_select_db($database_conn, $conn);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
```

and this is my form

```
<?php $i=0; do { $i++;?>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><?php echo $i;?></td>
        <input type="hidden" name="st_matrix_no[]" value="<?php echo $row_scs['st_matrix_no']; ?>"/></td>
         <td align="center" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><label>

      <select name="attend[]" id="attend">
                <option value="/" <?php if (!(strcmp("Present", $row_scs['at_status']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Present</option>
                <option value="O" <?php if (!(strcmp("Absent", $row_scs['at_status']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Absent</option>
              </select>
      </label></td>

      <input type="text" name="remarks[]" value="<?php echo $row_scs['at_remarks']; ?>" size="15" maxlength="20"/>  
      <input type="hidden" name="tt_staff_idx[]" value="<?php echo $row_scs['tt_staff_idx']; ?>"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="tt_idx[]" value="<?php echo $row_scs['tt_idx']; ?>"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="sb_name[]" value="<?php echo $row_scs['sb_name']; ?>"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="tt_class[]" value="<?php echo $row_scs['tt_class']; ?>"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="sb_code[]" value="<?php echo $row_scs['sb_code']; ?>"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="start" value="<?php echo $row_scs['tt_datetime_start'];?>" />
      <input type="hidden" name="end" value="<?php echo $row_scs['tt_datetime_end'];?>" />
      </td>
```

im so sorry! this is my second post. i didnt notice it! sorry peeps. this is my code. i want to store multiple row data in my database. but it cant. it just store one row only data. :((. i got so many student to mark attendance. please help? sorry for my bad english

Comment: Too much code. Try to only include the needed information rather than your entire code.

Comment: Exactly. What is your problem? Where is the problem. Don't post your entire web site here. It won't help us helping you...

Comment: mysql is deprecated. You may switch to mysqli or PDO

Comment: When your code is getting this big and sloppy you need to start separating the logic from the views or else you will end up with "spaghetti code". My advice, start with a small footprint MVC framework like Codeigniter. http://codeigniter.com

Comment: edited. SORRY PEEPS :(

Comment: What is this: `GetSQLValueString()` ?

Comment: GetSQLValueString() is function that generated from Dreamweaver automatically

Comment: Dreamweaver? figures.. I suggest you use Netbeans for PHP.

Comment: @CodeGodie alright! but can you solve my problem right now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the main problem I see is the way you are creating your HTML table. For the name attribute you are forcing an array, which is good but the way you have it:

```
<input type="hidden" name="tt_staff_idx[]" />
<input type="hidden" name="tt_idx[]"/>
<input type="hidden" name="sb_name[]" />
```

Will lead to this result:

```
tt_staff_idx = array("value1", "value2", "value3", etc...)
tt_idx= array("value1", "value2", "value3", etc...)
sb_name= array("value1", "value2", "value3", etc...)
```

Therefore, when you POST this information, you are probably only storing the very last value in the array.

What you need to do is setup your HTML inputs in a way that it builds a multi-dimensional array so you can iterate and store in your database. I would try something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="data[$i][tt_staff_idx]" />
<input type="hidden" name="data[$i][tt_idx]"/>
<input type="hidden" name="data[$i][sb_name]" />
```

so that you end up with this:

```
data= array(
   0 => array(
          tt_staff_idx => "";
          tt_idx=> "";
          sb_name=> "";
       )
   1 => array(
          tt_staff_idx => "";
          tt_idx=> "";
          sb_name=> "";
       )
)
```

Once you have this you can iterate in your PHP like this:

```
foreach($_POST['data'] as $data){
   ... your INSERT to DB code
}
```

Comment: update/edit your initial answe with what you have tried so that I can see what you did wrong

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL certainly only inserts one row of data

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, ...) VALUES ( %s, %s, ...)
```

You're going to need to loop through your form field arrays (`foreach`, `for`, `while`, *something* iterative) to end up with SQL that looks more like this if you want to insert them all at once

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, ...) VALUES ( %s, %s, ...), ( %s, %s, ...), ...
```

Comment: What `INSERT` query are you referring to specifically?

Comment: There are multiple ones

Comment: I only see `INSERT INTO attend (at_matrix_no, at_status, at_remarks, at_staff_idx, at_sb_name , at_class, at_sb_code, at_tt_idx) VALUES ( %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)`